# timeouts after multiple ajax calls

Tags: javascript, android, jquery-mobile, cordova

I'm working on a application in android with phonegap. So almost everything in my app. is done with javascript. I run into the problem described below. If anyone can tell me how to fix this I'd much obliged. So: please help!

If I click through my application, I get timeouts on my ajax requests. Once a timeout is generated all other requests also give timeouts. If I run this in a browser this problem does not occur. All calls are asynchronous. At times: multiple requests run in parallel while building up my page.

my code:

```
if (typeof TheApplication.webServiceCall !== 'function'){
    TheApplication.webServiceCall = function(uri, theType, async, data, callback, callbackError){

        var result;

        var successCallback = function (r) {

            TheApplication.user.name = r.username;

            $.ajax({
                url: baseUrl + uri,
                type: theType,
                async: async,
                data: data,
                dataType: 'json',
                timeout: 7000,
                cache: false,
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                beforeSend: function(xhr,settings) {
                    var authToken = r.authtoken;
                    xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization','Basic '+authToken);
                    xhr.setRequestHeader('max-age',0);
                    xhr.setRequestHeader('Expires','already expired');
                },
                success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                    if (data.Error.length > 0){
                        console.log("log TheApplication.webServiceCall error "+JSON.stringify(data.Error));
                        TheApplication.Error.Throw(data.Error);
                    }
                    result = callback(data);
                },
                error: function(xhr, options, error){
                    var errorMessage = JSON.stringify(error);
                    if (typeof callbackError === 'undefined' || callbackError == false) {
                        TheApplication.Error.Throw('UNKNOWN');
                    }
                    if(errorMessage == "" || (errorMessage.indexOf("timeout"))>0){
                        TheApplication.Error.Throw('NO_CONNECTION');
                    }
                }
            });

        };

        var failureCallback = function (e) {
            TheApplication.Error.Throw('UNKNOWN');
        };

        window.plugins.accountManager.getAccount(successCallback, failureCallback);
    };
}
```

Comment: if I force async to false (so synchronous operation) the problem seems not to occur.

Comment: I'm not into Android developing but multiple Ajax requests timing out simultaneously smalls like HTTP pipelining. Try forcing HTTP 1.0 and see if the requests still timeout together.